# How to use C++ memory management routines in Objective C module?

Tags: c++, ios, memory-management

I need to use C++ memory allocation routines in my Objective C iOS project. However, compiler does not recognize `new/delete` operators yielding `Use of undeclared identifier "new"`.

```
char *armsciiBuffer = new char[numberOfUnicodeChars];
...
delete [] armsciiBuffer;
```

What is the workaround here? I could use `malloc`, but new/delete would have been much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile the code as Objective-C++. Either add the `-x obj-c++` compiler flag, or name your source file `Foo.mm`.

Comment: It does work, but there might be some gotchas which will be revealed only through instruments. That was my question if there are any immediate troubles. The code in .m is pretty big. Anyway, thanks for answer.